# Efficient way of filling up the table with million empty rows

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, insert, common-table-expression

Do you know any efficient way of filling up the table with huge number of empty rows? Inserting them using  `WHILE` clause is not really efficient. There is definitely better way of filling up the table with empty rows than this:

```
DECLARE @CNT int
SET @CNT = 1
WHILE @CNT < 3
BEGIN
INSERT INTO TAB VALUES( '1' )
SET @CNT = @CNT + 1
END
```

I would like also to know, if it is possible to display let say 1 mil rows (numbered from 1 to 1000000) using `SELECT` clause and CTE (Common Table Expressions) without using any existing table.

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a way to generate a sequence of numbers:

```
SELECT TOP (1000000) n = CONVERT(INT, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id]))
INTO yourtable
FROM sys.all_objects AS s1 CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s2
OPTION (MAXDOP 1);

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX n ON yourtable(n)
-- WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE)
;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6477b/1) of 100 numbers being created.

This code is from [@Aaron Bertrand's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61305/aaron-bertrand) article [Generate a set or sequence without loops – part 1](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1). This article also includes other methods to generate the number sequence.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I am slowly learning the right way to do things. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dorepeat()
BEGIN
    SET @x = 0;
    REPEAT 
        INSERT INTO your_table (value) VALUES ("");
        SET @x = @x + 1; 
    UNTIL @x > 999999 END REPEAT;
END
```

I think that something like that is pretty fast.

Comment: Well a one-by-one loop is certainly not going to be "pretty fast" when there are better set-based alternatives available to you. Also, what platform is this for? Certainly doesn't look like SQL Server, which doesn't have keywords like `REPEAT` and `UNTIL`. It also uses  quoted identifiers as string delimiters (SQL Server uses `'single quotes'` to delimit strings) and I don't see where you've declared `@x`.

Comment: Yeah, this is true. The Server-Version was not gaven, when i worte the answer^^